# aiomysql and sqlalchemy basic example produces syntax error on python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I am trying to integrate sqlalchemy with aiomysql on python 3.6, using their official example on [github](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql#example-of-sqlalchemy-optional-integration) here is my full code

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import asyncio
from aiomysql.sa import create_engine

DB1 = dict(host="xxx",...)
DB2 = dict(host="yyy",...)

DATABASES = dict(db1=db1, db2=db2)

async def get_engine(loop, configs):
    configs = configs.copy()
    configs['loop'] = loop
    engine = await create_engine(**configs)
    return engine

class Engine(object):
    __shared_state = {}
    running = None

    def __init__(self, loop):
        print("init", Engine.running)
        self.__dict__ = Engine.__shared_state
        self.loop = loop
        if not Engine.running:
            self.ignite(loop)

    def connect(self, key, configs, loop):
        engine = loop.run_until_complete(get_engine(loop, configs))
        self.__dict__[key] = engine

    def ignite(self, loop):
        Engine.running = True
        for key, configs in DATABASES.items():
            self.connect(key, configs, loop)

def DoMyQueries(conn):
    pass

ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
engine = Engine(ioloop)
async with engine.db1.acquire() as conn:
    DoMyQueries(conn)

engine.db1.close()
await engine.wait_closed()
```

but i am getting the following error

```
 File "myfile.py", line 45
   async with engine.db1.acquire() as conn:
         ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what am i missing in my code? I know the error is pretty obvious but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async with` can occur only inside `async def .`  Move your code into an `async def main()` and call it with `run_until_complete()`